# Prove that if {$a_n$ } is a sequence that converges to A and $a_n$ ≥ 0 for all n then A ≥ 0.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Prove that if {$a_n$} is a sequence that converges to A and $a_n$ $\geq$ 0 for all n, then A $\geq$ 0.

I have assumed on that contrary that A < 0. Pick $\epsilon$ = |A| > 0. Now, |$a_n$ - A| = $a_n$ - A $\geq$ -A = |A|. This is a contradiction because by definition of convergence, we have to have for all $\epsilon$ > 0, there exists a natural number N such that for all n $\geq$ N, |$a_n$ - A| < $\epsilon$=|A|. Therefore, A $\geq$ 0.

Is this correct?

Comment: Why do you have a problem with "the condition that there exists a natural number N such that for all n ≥ N, and so on"?

Comment: Well, now that I look at it again, maybe there isn't a problem there. I just edited my solution a bit to word it a little better. Does the proof see valid to you?

Comment: No, you made at least one more turnaround in the proof by contradiction than is commendable. If you insist on assuming that $A\lt0$, continue with $|a_n-A|=a_n-A$ since $a_n\geqslant0$ and $-A\gt0$.

Comment: $|a_n|+|A|>|A|$ (which is not necessarily true) does not contradict $|a_n-A|<|A|$, since $|A|$ might lie between $|a_n-A|$ and $|A|+|a_n|$. However what is true is $|a_n-A|=a_n-A\ge-A=|A|$

Comment: I don't understand the question. You've given a proposal for proof. Are you asking if it is correct? I don't see the  contradiction you claim to exist. **Edit:** If you're able to write in $\TeX$ why not write directly in the question instead of somewhere else and posting an image?

Comment: @DavidPeterson I do see where i made my mistake now. So since -A > 0, -A = |A|. That's how you get the last part of your suggestion correct?

Comment: @mmm yes (..random characters)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your proof is valid, but I also think that there are a few things you could have left out..

So your conclusion is that $A<0$ implies the contradiction $a_n+|A|<|A|$ and $a_n+|A|>|A|$. This means that the assumption that $A<0$ is wrong. To get these to inequality we use the property of a the converging sequence. Here is what i mean:

First the easy inequality:

$a_n+|A|>|A|$

Where we used the $a_n\ge0$ for all $n$.

And the converging sequence property. Choose $\epsilon=|A|$

$|a_n-A|<|A|$

But since $-A$ is always negative we have the equality:$a_n+|A|=|a_n-A|$ and therefore:

$a_n+|A|=|a_n-A|<|A|$

And here we have the contradiction. (This is of course just for $n>N$ for some $N$, but i hope this is implied)